# wordpress delete unwanted location

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMgcO.png)I'm building a website using WordPress. I'm trying to set a video as the background, but there are some black areas. I can change the black areas by changing the color in the global settings, but I can't remove them. How can I remove these areas or add a video?"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUOVl.png)

I'm not familiar with this topic. Could you provide the CSS code you recommended? It could be a setting as well